# Why are we checking for n.parent == null?

Tags: java, graph, tree

I am finding the 'next' node (i.e., in-order successor) of a given node in a binary search tree.

Why is this condition used in the code given below:

- ***if (n.parent == null || n.right != null)***

**My question is: Why are we checking for n.parent == null ?**

Full Code:

```
public static TreeNode inorderSucc(TreeNode n) { 
    if (n == null) return null;

    // Found right children -> return left most node of right subtree
    if (n.parent == null || n.right != null) { 
        return leftMostChild(n.right); 
    } else { 
        TreeNode q = n;
        TreeNode x = q.parent;
        // Go up until we’re on left instead of right
        while (x != null && x.left != q) {
            q = x;
            x = x.parent;
        }
        return x;
    }  
} 

public static TreeNode leftMostChild(TreeNode n) {
    if (n == null) {
        return null;
    }
    while (n.left != null) {
        n = n.left; 
    }
    return n; 
}
```

Comment: What if the very first node you touch (being the very middle node of the BST) is the only node you need? e.g. Doing a search through a binary tree where the initial node contains the value you're trying to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (n.parent == null || n.right != null)
```

Checking if `n` is the **root** node and it has a right subtree.